# mysqli_query while loop to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to upgrade my way to fetch data from sql from mysqli_query to fetchall.

```
$res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM forum_index WHERE forum_over='yes'");
        while ($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        ......
    }
```

So when I use fetchAll() I'll get an array, Am I supposed to use foreach() then or is there a smarter way of doing this?

And to collect a single value from the DB this is the right way right?

```
$fid = (int)$_GET['id'];
$thread = $db->query("SELECT * FROM forum_threads WHERE f_id=".$fid)->fetch_array();
    echo $thread['id'];
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to switch to `fetchAll` when you switch to PDO? it has `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, which allows you to keep the same structure.

Comment: So how would you convert:
$res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM forum_index WHERE forum_over='yes'");
        while ($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        ......
    }
? Sorry, trying to get my head around it :)

Comment: I already answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `fetchAll()` just because you're using PDO. If the query returns a large amount of data, this could slow things down because it has to collect it all into memory. You can use the same kind of loop as in your mysqli code:

```
$res = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM forum_index WHERE forum_over='yes'");
while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ...
}
```

As to your second question, you should use a parametrized query, not substitute variables.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_threads WHERE f_id= :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Now I see how its works, thank you for your explanation Barmar.
I need to read some more about pdo, but you solved my current problem. Thanks!